# Identifying negative-clusters in a GPS dataset

Tags: gps, data-science, cluster-analysis, gis

I have a dataset of GPS positions that I have used a KMeans clustering technique to identify clusters for using Python.  I now want to identify regions in the data that have limited or no points, almost the inverse of the KMeans clustering.  Is there a statistical technique that can do this and could someone post an example using Python?

[I am trying to identify the areas circled in blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PwnB.png)

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but could you not just simply split your area into squares, and then count how many points are in each square?

The size of squares depends on the granularity; you could use small squares, and then join squares with fewer points than a specific threshold to form larger areas. Obviously you need to set a threshold depending on square size: the smaller the squares, the lower the threshold needs to be.